# How can I pass a User model into a form field (django)?

Tags: django, encryption, field, formfield

Basically, I need to use the User's password hash to encrypt some data via a custom model field. Check out the snippet I used here: [Django Encryption](http://bryanhelmig.com/django-encryption/).

I tried this:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product_id = EncryptedCharField(max_length=255, user_field=owner)

.................................................................................

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'max_length': self.max_length, 'user_field': self.user_field}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(EncryptedCharField, self).formfield(**defaults))
```

But when I try to use user_field, I get a ForeignKey instance (of course!):

```
user_field = kwargs.get('user_field')
cipher = user_field.password[:32]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this - override the save() method where you can call encrypt method.

for decrypt you can use [signal post_init](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/), so every time you instantiate the model from the database the product_id field is decrypted automatically

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    user_field = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product_id = EncryptedCharField()
    ...other fields...

    def save(self):
        self.product_id._encrypt(product_id, self.user_field)
        super(MyClass,self).save()

    def decrypt(self):
        if self.product_id != None:
            user = self.user_field
            self.product_id._decrypt(user=user)

def post_init_handler(sender_class, model_instance):
    if isinstance(model_instance, MyClass):
        model_instance.decrypt()

from django.core.signals import post_init
post_init_connect.connect(post_init_handler)


obj = MyClass(user_field=request.user) 
#post_init will be fired but your decrypt method will have
#nothing to decrypt, so it won't garble your input
#you'll either have to remember not to pass value of crypted fields 
#with the constructor, or enforce it with either pre_init method 
#or carefully overriding __init__() method - 
#which is not recommended officially

#decrypt will do real decryption work when you load object form the database

obj.product_id = 'blah'
obj.save() #field will be encrypted
```

maybe there is a more elegant "pythonic" way of doing this

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply! Hopefully I can come up with something that resembles this. But, do you any basic example on how one would accomplish that with a signal? I've got very limited knowledge on signals as a whole...

Comment: THANKS! Wow, I am really impressed. I'll definitely be giving this a spin later. Thanks again!