# Can I hash/encrypt or otherwise protect emails in my Django app from hackers?

Tags: django, django-email

Hoping for a simple function I can use to store emails securely and retrieve easily when required to send emails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kind of a general question, but here are a few solutions I'm familiar with:

- use [django-encrypted-fields](https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields), which has an EncryptedEmailField
- you can override the save method for encrypting the email yourself, then override the post_init signal for decryption. See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743764/how-can-i-pass-a-user-model-into-a-form-field-django) (which is based on [this](http://bryanhelmig.com/django-encryption/))
- you can build your own encrypted email field, see [django snippet here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1095/) (uses pyCrypto)
- you can use django-extension's [EncryptedCharField](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/encrypted.py)
- If none of the above seems good enough, try google-ing around by yourself. You're probably not the first to tackle this problem

good luck.

Comment: I'm sure I can get one of those to work. Thanks for the quick summary of options.